# Scrubbed on the paper vs scrubbed at the paper

Tags: prepositions

I was reading a novel. And in the novel I read a sentence where the writer wrote *scrubbed at the paper* but as per my opinion it should have been *scrubbed on the paper*. Because the preposition *at* shows a location. So, if the writer wanted to show the location then it sounds fine. But if the writer wanted to tell that something he scrubbed and he did on a piece of  paper then I think the preposition *on* should have been used instead *at*.

Comment: Try some dictionaries? In one so-so dictionary, it has the example: *"she **scrubbed** furiously **at** the plates."*

Answer (score 2):

*At* does not always signify location; it may also signify direction.

In object/complement position, a directional *at* phrase is often used instead of a simple noun phrase or a more conventional preposition to express a higher degree of energy and effort. It represents its object as in some sense a target of that effort.

> He worked on finishing his essay *tells you only what the object of his work was, but*
> He worked **at** finishing his essay *suggests that finishing the essay was a matter of some urgency.*

With verbs of motion an *at* phrase usually implies intention to collide:

> He drove into the wall *could be accidental, but*
> He drove **at** the wall *can only be deliberate*.
>
> The child ran to her mother *suggests only desire to get close to her mother, but*
> The child ran **at** her mother *implies a desire to attack her mother.*
>
> The police charged the crowd *implies merely that the police advanced swiftly toward the crowd, but* The police charged at the crowd *implies that they intended violent action.*

In your example,

> He scrubbed the paper *suggests only an attempt to clean it, and*
> He scrubbed on the paper *merely tells you where his scrubbing took place, but*
> He scrubbed **at** the paper *suggests a strenuous effort; depending on the context, it may imply a strong emotion behind the effort, such as anger or frustration.*

Comment: _The police charged the crowd / The police charged toward the crowd_, both are OK?

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng Oh, yes. *Toward* suggests only that they started charging in that direction, not that they actually reached the crowd.

Comment: I thought only _the police **was charging** toward the crowd_ was OK, but both are right.

Answer (score 0):

OALD describes the usage of [*scrub (at something)*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/scrub_1#scrub_1__4) The example there is

> *The woman **scrubbed at** her face with a tissue.*

Another example:

> She cursed, ***scrubbed at the paper,*** trying to dry it. And then it tore, nearly in half. This made tears creep to her eyes, she was not sure why.

The OALD page does not describe any usage such as *scrub (on something)*. Interestingly, [the Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/scrub_1?q=scrubbed) says using *at* is an optional in its example.

But when I searched, [I found that *scrubbed on* is possible](http://www.citizen-times.com/story/life/2014/07/12/nancy-williams-shares-thoughts-airplane-flights/12575091/) but then it is in a different way.

> This week I was wiped and rubbed. ***A little cotton pad was scrubbed on*** my hands, then put into a machine, which checks it for terrorist-type chemicals.

So, the correct expression will be using *scrubbed at* as the author wrote it.